# Why am I getting permission denied error in Google Colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to train a GPT-2 model on Google Colab following this tutorial : [Tutorial Link](https://towardsdatascience.com/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-train-gpt-2-on-books-using-google-colab-b3c6fa15fef0)

But when I enter this line of code :

```
!PYTHONPATH=src ./train.py --dataset src/corpus/tdata.txt --model_name '345M' --batch_size 1 --learning_rate 0.00001
```

This gives me the error :

```
/bin/bash: ./train.py: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

How do I give superuser permissions in Google Colab ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the permissions on train.py or its parent directory: Open a new cell and enter:

```
!chmod 755 -R <dir_path>
```